# How to use @mixin inside sass file when loading files with webpack 2?

Tags: webpack, sass

I cannot get my compiled css to use any of the @mixins that are inside my scss. There is no error in the console during compile so I am not even sure where to start investigating.

My setup is as follows:

**main.scss:**

```
@charset 'UTF-8';

@import 'base/mixins';
@import 'components/button';
```

**button.scss**

```
#button {
  color: yellow;
  @mixin desktop-up {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

**_mixins.scss**

```
$desktop-width: 992px;

@mixin desktop-up {
  @media (min-width: #{$desktop-width + 1}) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

And my webpack 2 config looks like this *(the relevant parts)*:

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, ''),
  devtool: debug ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
  entry: ['./js/app.ts', './sass/main.scss'],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
         'style-loader',
         {
           loader: "css-loader",
           options: {
             modules: true,
             importLoaders: 1
           }
         }
        ]
      },
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            {loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: function () {
                  return [
                    require('postcss-smart-import'),
                    require('precss'),
                    require('autoprefixer')
                  ];
                }
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./sass")]
              }
            }
          ]
      }
      // ....
    ]
  },
// .......
```

The weird thing is that inside my button.scss file I have access to the **$desktop-width** variable, but the @mixin does nothing. It's never applied that I can see and it throws no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not your configuration. You are using the mixins in a wrong way:
 `@mixin` is for defining the mixin. You have to use `@include desktop-up;`in your `buttons.scss`.

Look here:
http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6